# Tab indentation in CoffeeScript using Emacs

Tags: emacs, coffeescript

I hope this is within the reasonable scope of this site and not too trivial, this is my first post.  I am new to Emacs and am trying to set up the environment so that when I start a new line in `coffee-mode` the automatic indentation is in the form of tabs.  As I understood the documentation of `coffee-mode` all I need to do is set `coffee-indent-tabs-mode` to `t`.  I've appended my init file with the code below:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(coffee-tab-width 2)
 '(coffee-indent-tabs-mode t))
```

However when I start Emacs and open a .coffee file, though it gets the tab width right, when I press enter it indents with spaces.  Quibbles about whether I need to indent with tabs aside, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have an older version of coffee.el so I can't test it, but have you tried setting the `coffee-tab-width` to one? It seems to me like the current column number gets divided by the tab width and that might have strange consequences.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. I just tried that, added a line to a file, but when I checked there were still simply spaces at the start of the new line I'd made rather than tabs, so I'm not sure that's the issue?  I could always use `tabify` but it's not really satisfactory...

Comment: Did you set the variables with custom or did you add that to your `.emacs`? This could lead to problems, there only should be one block of `custom-set-variables` in your `.emacs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the coffee-mode I find in GNU ELPA, there is no `coffee-indent-tabs-mode`.  I recommend you simply do:

```
(add-hook 'coffee-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'tab-width) 2)
            (set (make-local-variable 'indent-tabs-mode) t)))
```

This should work for pretty much any major mode.